# Send email with attachment (sendRawEmail) not sending email when running on aws lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, email-attachments, amazon-ses

I have the following code, which works good when I am running the code locally, it successfully sends the email, but when placing the same code on AWS lambda (NO VPC and with the SES full access properties role) it doesn't send the email, what am I doing wrong?

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
aws.config.update({
  "region": "eu-west-1",
  accessKeyId: 'myAccessKey',
  secretAccessKey: 'mySecretAccessKey'
});

/**
 * Send email with attachment.
 * 
 * @param {string} sourceEmail
 * @param {string} toEmail
 * @param {string} subject
 * @param {string} body
 * @param {string} fileName
 * @param {buffer} attachmentBuffer
 * 
 * @returns {void}
 */
module.exports.sendEmailWithAttachment = async (sourceEmail, toEmail, subject, body, fileName, attachmentBuffer) => {

    try {

        var sesEmail = "From: '" + subject + "' <" + sourceEmail + ">\n";
        sesEmail += "To: " + toEmail + "\n";
        sesEmail += "Subject: " + subject + "\n";
        sesEmail += "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
        sesEmail += "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"NextPart\"\n\n";
        sesEmail += "--NextPart\n";
        sesEmail += "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";
        sesEmail += body+"\n\n";
        sesEmail += "--NextPart\n";
        sesEmail += "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"" + fileName + "\"\n";
        sesEmail += "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n";
        sesEmail += "Content-Disposition: attachment\n\n";
        sesEmail += attachmentBuffer.toString("base64").replace(/([^\0]{76})/g, "$1\n") + "\n\n";
        sesEmail += "--NextPart--";

        var params = {
            RawMessage: {Data: sesEmail},
            Source: "'"+ subject + "' <" + sourceEmail + ">'"
        };


        await new aws.SES().sendRawEmail(params).promise();        


    } catch (err){

        console.log(err);
    }
};
```

The source email is whitelisted as verified on AWS SES dashboard as well.

Also to be noted that I don't see any errors on the cloudwatch logs.

Does anyone have any idea on what I am missing?

Locally runs without any problems! The attachment goes nicely as well.

Thanks.

Comment: can you share your lambda logs and region ?

Comment: thanks for your help, its working already, I was not awaiting on this function call that I pasted here, after placing the 'await' before calling it worked, thank you anyway! (it was working on my machine locally without the await because maybe it was to fast comparing to executing on lambda)